# How to shutdown wordpress login temporarily

Tags: login

How can I disable wordpress login temporarily even for administrator users? is there any solution?

Comment: Is this just for preventing logging in or does this also cover forcing the logout of all the people that are already authenticated?

Answer (score 3):

You could hook into the [`wp_authenticate_user` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_authenticate_user/) and return an error.

Something like:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'wpse_406123_stop_login', -1 );

function wpse_406123_stop_login() {
    $message = new WP_Error( 'login_disabled', __( '<strong>ERROR</strong>: You cannot login at this time' ) );
    return $message;
}
```

You can then change your security keys -[the ones that look like this](https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/) to something different - that will invalidate all current logins.

Comment: Didn't noticed you had already posted, deleted mine :-)

Comment: ps: I'm still able to login with your code though, maybe I will undelete mine to test further :-)

Comment: Nice thorough answer below @birgire - upvoted! Did you change the security keys? I've also changed the priority to make sure it runs before anything else. Should help. I will admit to not testing this - this was a codex eye-baller.

Comment: Thanks @Bysander, it could also be that my test install is not in a got shape and in a need of a total replacement :-)

Comment: Just tested & changed hook `wp_authenticate_user` is the right one

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to halt the login by returning an error through the `wp_authenticate_user` filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', function() {
    return new WP_Error( 'authentication_failed', esc_html__( 'Login disabled.', 'wpse' ) );
} );
```

so that you will get a notice about that after trying to login:

[image]

But it will be better if users don't have to login in the first place to get the message. We can add a message like:

```
add_filter( 'login_message', function( $message ) {
     return sprintf ( 
         '<p class="message">%s</p>', 
         esc_html__( ' Login is disabled!  ⛔', 'wpse' ) 
     ) . $message;
} );
```

That will show up as:

[image]

... or maybe it's better to just hide the form in the first place with e.g.:

```
add_action( 'login_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_add_inline_style( 
        'login', 
        ' body.login #loginform, 
          body.login #nav,
          body.login .language-switcher {
             display:none;
          }' 
    );
} );
```

in addition to the above steps.

That will give us:

[image]

We note that to remove the sessions for the current user there's the `wp_destroy_all_sessions()` function if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Wow - lots of great solutions offered....silly me, I just remove the wp-login.php file from the server, and - if as Tom Nowell asks - any currently logged-in users need to be booted out, I change the salt keys in wp-config.php.

If you want to be more polite, you could swap the wp-login.php file for one that has just a nice message instead of the login form.

No coding necessary, although this is definitely the lazier solution!

Comment: ps: there is a way for users to gain access to WordPress CRUD even if wp-login.php file is missing, i.e. through the XML-RPC API.

Comment: Yes indeed you are correct, but since I don't use the REST API, I have XML-RPC shut down as well.  You can either use a plugin to do that, or you can simply remove that file (xmlrpc.php) from the server also, which is what I do.  Mine is admittedly a lazy solution but my users' needs are very simple so I have the luxury of a simple solution.